"React Native Build Failed: 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect' Error during Gradle Configuration"
(node:19384) ExperimentalWarning: CommonJS module C:\Users\vvija\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\debug\src\node.js is loading ES Module C:\Users\vvija\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\supports-color\index.js using require().
Support for loading ES Module in require() is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)
(node:18568) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...
13 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 10 up-to-date
info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.


Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 2s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > Failed to notify project evaluation listener. > The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 2s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
